# How to sum two unequal length vector by Date in r?

Tags: r, tidyverse

The lengths of two datasets are unequal but they have the same variables. I want to sum the "value" variables of these two datasets by "Date".

Dataset 1:

| Date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2000 | 1 |
| 2/1/2000 | 1 |
| 3/1/2000 | 2 |
| 4/1/2000 | 3 |
| 5/1/2000 | 4 |
| 6/1/2000 | 5 |
| 7/1/2000 | 2 |

Dataset 2:

| Date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2/1/2000 | 5 |
| 3/1/2000 | 7 |
| 5/1/2000 | 2 |
| 7/1/2000 | 9 |

Expected outcome:

| Date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2000 | 1 |
| 2/1/2000 | 6 |
| 3/1/2000 | 9 |
| 4/1/2000 | 3 |
| 5/1/2000 | 6 |
| 6/1/2000 | 5 |
| 7/1/2000 | 11 |

---

Update - My solution

Personally, I prefer to `rbind` two data frames and use `group_by` to `summarise` the sum of the `value`.

The code is as below:

```
#The two datasets are named 'a' and 'b' respectively.

library(tidyverse)

a = do.call(rbind,list(a,b))

a %>% group_by(Date) %>%
      summarise(value = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest option would be a `powerjoin`:

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_inner_join(
  df1, df2, 
  by = "Date", 
  conflict = sum
)
```

---

But here, a simple `match` should suffice as well:

```r
df1$value <- df1$value + df2$value[match(df1$Date, df2$Date)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know I can accept answer, I am new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1):

You can `aggregate` the combined data frames by `sum`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(10957, 10958, 10959, 10960, 
10961, 10962, 10963), class = "Date"), value = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
df2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(10958, 10959, 10961, 10963), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(5, 7, 2, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

aggregate(value ~ Date, rbind(df1, df2), sum)
        Date value
1 2000-01-01     1
2 2000-01-02     6
3 2000-01-03     9
4 2000-01-04     3
5 2000-01-05     6
6 2000-01-06     5
7 2000-01-07    11
```